# My 'ctrl+x' shortcut stops working randomly on ubuntu 18.04.2 and works again after a reboot

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've tested the specific keys (both `ctrl` and the `x` key) and they work singularly, but they don't work together. On the other hand `ctrl+c,v,a` all work as they should. This goes on until I reboot and then everything works fine again for a while.

Trying it on http://keyboardchecker.com/ all keys work fine and `ctrl+` any key also works except for `x`.

As maybe useful info I'm generally using vscode and chrome, no other softwares running.

I have no idea how to reproduce this, any help would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to cut/paste text or files?

Comment: neither files in explorer nor text in vscode

Comment: I updated my kernel to `uname -v
#201905161442 SMP Thu May 16 18:44:30 UTC 2019` but the problem still stays. If I kill the gnome process then restarting it fixes the ctrl+x shortcut. I have no idea how else to test it

Comment: Did you fix this? - I'm having the same issue but with left ctrl modifier, regardless of the combining key. I'm on Manjaro, with kernel 5.13.19-2-MANJARO